# cardlayout vs memory efficiency

Tags: java, swing, memory-management, cardlayout

Is usage of cardlayout memory efficient? For example if i load 20 JPanel's into cardlayout, it would probably occupy a lot of memory space. Would it be better to load few panels and later load some more and unload panels that won't be used any more?

Comment: I think that more organized your JPanels form would be if u use TabbedPane, as @Robin mentioned memory usage would be more less the same, all in all u can add more memory to ur JVM by 'java -jar -Xmx2048m yourjar.jar'

Comment: *"For example if i load 20 JPanel's into cardlayout, it would probably occupy a lot of memory space."*  The JRE can store 10s of thousands of panels using typical default memory size.  So 'probably not'.  It depends how you define 'a lot', but remember that memory is cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be better to load few panels and later load some more and unload panels that won't be used any more

A `CardLayout` will indeed keep strong references to all `Component`s which are added to it. So yes, from a memory point of view it would be better to remove `Component`s again if you won't need them anymore.

> Is usage of cardlayout memory efficient

Probably about as efficient as any other layout. The only difference is that you only see 1 panel at the same time when using a `CardLayout`. Butting adding 20 panels to a `CardLayout` will more or less use the same amount of memory as adding them to a `FlowLayout`